# Error in ng build with flags angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an error when I try to build my app with some flags,
if I try to build it with only `ng build` it works but if I use this flags:
`ng build -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimize`

I have this errors:

> Configuration ',,' could not be found in project 'rebus-cli'. Error:
>   Configuration ',,' could not be found in project 'rebus-cli'.
>       at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:106:23)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap
>   [as project]
>   (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:64:55)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:122:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:112:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
>       at TapSubscriber._next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:109:26)
>       at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:141:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Workspace\rebus\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)

I don't have any errors in `angular.json` file

Comment: Downvoting without an answer is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--code-coverage` instead of `-cc` - seems sth. is mixed up with the `-c` --configuration option.